# Android fragment not being removed or replaced

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm trying to remove or replace a fragment from a container. The fragment is created on onCreate() of the activity and should disappear once buttons are clicked. However, I can't remove or replace the fragment.

Out of desperation I tried to replace the container with a blank fragment of the same background colour, however the blank fragment just gets displayed below the other fragment instead of it being replaced. I have a method for clearing all fragments which works in every instance except dashboardInfoFragment. I'm not sure if it's because I'm creating it in onCreate() or whether it's something else I can't identify. I get the same results using replace as I do for add with the fragment transaction. I've never been able to remove a single fragment from this app but clearFragments() works for every other fragment.

I've looked through countless posts on this topic and tried everything but I can't remove this fragment by reference to the fragment or by tag or in clearFragments() so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the relevant snippet of the activity

```
public class DashboardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DashboardInfoFragment dashboardInfoFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

    dashboardInfoFragment = DashboardInfoFragment.newInstance();
    replaceFragment(R.id.dashboard_table_fragment_place, dashboardInfoFragment, "dashboardInfoFragment");

    menuButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (!isClassMenuOpen) {
                startClassMenu();

            } else {
                clearAllFragments();
                startClassMenu();
            }
        }
    });

    homeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clearAllFragments();

            replaceFragment(R.id.dashboard_table_fragment_place,     dashboardInfoFragment, "dashboardInfoFragment");
        }
    });
}

public void startClassMenu() {
    clearAllFragments();

// This doesn't work
    removeSingleFragment(R.id.dashboard_table_fragment_place, dashboardInfoFragment, "dashboardInfoFragment");

    dashboardInfoFragment = DashboardInfoFragment.newInstance();
    replaceFragment(R.id.dashboard_table_fragment_place, dashboardInfoFragment, "dashboardInfoFragment");

// Trying to replace with blank fragment but gets displayed below the dashboardInfoFragment
    blankFragment = BlankFragment.newInstance();
    replaceFragment(R.id.dashboard_table_fragment_place, blankFragment, "blankFragment");

    ClassMenuFragment classMenuFragment = ClassMenuFragment.newInstance(classList);
    replaceFragment(R.id.class_menu_fragment_place, classMenuFragment, "classMenuFragment");
}

// Removes all fragments except for dashboardInfoFragment
public void clearAllFragments() {

    try {
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

        isClassMenuOpen = false;
        isSettingsMenuOpen = false;
        isModuleOptionsMenuOpen = false;

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void replaceFragment(int id, Fragment fragment, String tag) {
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(id, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(tag);
    transaction.commit();
}


    // Some of my attempts at removing the fragment
public void removeSingleFragment(int container, Fragment fragment, String tag) {
//    if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(container) != null) {
//        getSupportFragmentManager()
//                    .beginTransaction().
//                            remove(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(container)).commit();
//        }
//
//        getSupportFragmentManager()
//                .beginTransaction()
//                .replace(container, fragment)
//                .commit();

        //FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

//        if (fragment != null) {
//            transaction.remove(fragment);
//              transaction.commit().setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
//            fragment = null;
//
//        }
            FragmentManager fragmentManager =  getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction =  fragmentManager.beginTransaction();


    if(fragment!=null&&fragment.isAdded()) {
        transaction =  fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.remove(fragment);
        transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE);
        transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }

    transaction =  fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(container, fragment, tag).commit();
}
        }

    });
```

}

Comment: What is `replaceFragment()`?

Comment: Hi there. I've added replaceFragment() in as I forgot it

Comment: Don't use `addToBackStack()`. That tells the FragmentManager that you want to keep that Fragment ready to be displayed.

Comment: What should I use instead?

Comment: Why do you think it's needed?

Comment: I got the code from SO and it seemed to work fine so I've been using it. Can I just take out that line or do I need to replace it with something else? If thought I'd be able to reference them by their tag which is why I thought I'd need it

Comment: You can just take it out. You shouldn't even need tags for what it looks like you're doing.

Comment: I've taken the line out but no changes in the results

Comment: Try adding `transaction.addToBackStack(null)`  before `transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();` to see if it works.

Comment: Sadly no difference was made to removing this fragment but it did help me with another fragment I was having issues with removing.